# Do I need to register JavaTimeModule while using JDK 11?

Tags: java, jackson, java-11, jackson-modules

I just found out that when I used JDK 8 I had to register JavaTimeModule to add support for java.time API.

```
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

Otherwise I would get an error like this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.datab
ind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING
```

However, when I moved to JDK 11, I noticed that it works even without registering the module. 
Even if I just try to run the same application on two different JDKs(8/11) (without changing other libraries versions) it still doesn't work for JDK 8 without registering the module yet works for JDK 11.

I can't find any specific serializers/deserializes that would help JDK 11 to handle it on its own. Was anything actually added to JDK or other libraries to make it not required to register new JavaTimeModule? Otherwise, I would be extra careful when thinking of the fact of adding it or omitting it.

Comment: What version of FasterXML are you using?

Comment: FasterXML Version 2.9.8

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the current (Data Binding 2.11.x) behavior of `registerModule` is to quietly do nothing if you attempt to register a type module that is already registered and if the `IGNORE_DUPLICATE_MODULE_REGISTRATIONS` mapper feature is is true.  (It is true by default.)

So I surmise from what you say that the date/time module is auto-registering Java 11.

On the other hand, it is should also be safe to manually register any module irrespective of auto-registration.

Note: this will all change in Data Binding 3.x.  For a start `registerModule`  has been removed in the "master" branch.

Comment: But, why does it do it only for java 11? Is there a version check of the runtime environment? What "registerModule" was replaced with in 3.x?

Comment: 1)  Don't know.  2) Don't know.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, just wanna know what happens under the hood. Kind of interesting how they achieved that.

Comment: The source code is available if you want to satisfy your curiosity.   Download it and look.